# Find the area of the triangle defined in the figure provided

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Find the area of the triangle defined in the figure below

[image]

This question appeared in a math olympiad contest and was considered invalid later on without any specific reason. Is it solvable? If yes, provide the answer!

Comment: You have three equations that include the three sides. create those equation by relation to the radius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

In $\triangle ABC$,
$|BC|=a$, $|CA|=b$, $|AB|=c$,
points $D,E,F$ are midpoints,
$|D_1D_2|=|E_1E_2|=|F_1F_2|=2\,R$.

Using the power of a points $D,E$ and $F$ with respect to
the circumscribed circle with radius $R$, we have

\begin{align}
\tfrac{a}2\cdot\tfrac{a}2&=2\cdot(2\,R-2)
,\\
\tfrac{b}2\cdot\tfrac{b}2&=1\cdot(2\,R-1)
,\\
\tfrac{c}2\cdot\tfrac{c}2&=3\cdot(2\,R-3)
,\\
a&=4\sqrt{R-1}
,\\
b&=2\sqrt{2\,R-1}
,\\
c&=2\sqrt{6\,R-9}
,\\
S&=\frac{a\,b\,c}{4\,R}
=\frac{4\sqrt3}R\,\sqrt{(R-1)(2\,R-1)(2\,R-3)}\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
S&=\tfrac14\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}
=4\sqrt{R\,(2\,R-3)}\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

From $\eqref{1}=\eqref{2}$
we have
\begin{align}
3\,(R-1)(2\,R-1)(2\,R-3)
&=
R^3
,
\end{align}

and as it was noted 
in the comments, this results in a cubic equation

\begin{align}
R^3-6\,R^2+9\,R-3&=0 \tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Using substitution $R=2\,t+2$ and dividing the resulting equation by 2,
we get

\begin{align}
4\,t^3-3\,t-\tfrac12&=0
.
\end{align}

Using identity 
\begin{align}
4\,\cos^3\phi-3\,\cos\phi&=\cos3\phi
\end{align}

for $\cos3\phi=\tfrac12$,

\begin{align}
t&=\cos\phi
=\cos\left(
\tfrac13(\arccos\tfrac12+2\pi k)
\right)
=\cos
\frac{\pi\,(1+6 k)}9
,\quad k=0,1,2
.
\end{align}
Thus there are three real solutions for \eqref{3},
\begin{align}
R_0&=2+2\cos\tfrac\pi9\approx 3.87938524157182
,\\
R_1&=2+2\cos\tfrac{7\pi}9\approx 0.467911113762044
,\\
R_2&=2+2\cos\tfrac{13\pi}9\approx 1.65270364466614
,
\end{align}

and the only valid solution that
satisfies condition $R>3$
is $R=2+2\cos\tfrac\pi9$, which gives the area

\begin{align}
S&=4\sqrt{R\,(2\,R-3)}
=4\sqrt2\sqrt{(\cos\tfrac\pi9+1)(4\,\cos\tfrac\pi9+1)}
\approx 17.1865547357625
.
\end{align}

Comment: +1 cool. I also get essentially same expression in $\cos\frac{\pi}{18}$ but in a more convoluted way...

Comment: Great(+1). Just for completeness, for those asking whether there is a way to express $\cos \frac{\pi}{9}$ using radicals or simple expressions, see the discussion on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/593412/460565) related to  $\sin \frac{\pi}{9}$.

Answer (score 1):

If the circle has radius $r>3$ then the three sides of the triangle are tangent to concentric circles having radii $r-1,r-2,r-3$.

Then using just the Pythagorean relationship the lengths of the three sides of the triangle are $2\sqrt{2r-1},2\sqrt{4r-4},2\sqrt{6r-9}$.

So long as $\sqrt{2r-1}+\sqrt{4r-4}\ge\sqrt{6r-9}$ there will be a solution corresponding to $r$.

It is easily verified that solutions exist for $r=4, r=5$, whose areas will be different.
[image: triangle in circle]

Comment: $r = 4$ or $5$ are not solutions. The circumradius of the triangle formed from $2\sqrt{2r-1}$, $2\sqrt{4r-4}$,$2\sqrt{6r-9}$  also need to equal to $r$. This force $r$ to be about $3.879385241571816$ (a root of the cubic equation $r^3-6r^2+9r-3 = 0$) and area $\approx 17.18655473576248$.

Comment: @achille: in other words, $R=2+2\cos\tfrac\pi9$

Comment: @achillehui Agreed