# Is there a way to find the exact values of $\sin(\frac{π}{9})$ and $\cos(\frac{π}{9})$

Tags: trigonometry

Okay so I wanted to calculate the exact irrational values of $\sin(\frac{π}{9})$ and $\cos(\frac{π}{9})$, but I keep running into a bit of a problem.

Let's take the sine as an example: 
$\because \sin(3x) = 3\sin(x) - 4\sin^{3}(x)$ 
$\therefore \sin(x) = 3\sin(\frac{x}{3}) - 4\sin^{3}(\frac{x}{3})$ 
$\therefore -4\sin^{3}(\frac{x}{3}) + 3\sin(\frac{x}{3}) - \sin(x) = 0$ 
$\therefore \sin^{3}(\frac{x}{3}) - \frac{3\sin(\frac{x}{3})}{4} + \frac{\sin(x)}{4} = 0$ 
Plugging in $\frac{π}{3}$ for $x$, we get:
$\sin^{3}(\frac{π}{9}) - \frac{3\sin(\frac{π}{9})}{4} + \frac{\sin(\frac{π}{3})}{4} =$ 
 $\sin^{3}(\frac{π}{9}) - \frac{3\sin(\frac{π}{9})}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8} = 0$ 
Now we have a depressed cubic equation; We can solve depressed cubic equations with the formula:
$$x^{3} + px + q$$
$$x = \sqrt[3]{\frac{-q}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{q^{2}}{4} + \frac{p^{3}}{27}}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{-q}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{q^{2}}{4} + \frac{p^{3}}{27}}}$$
Plugging in our values, we get:
$\sin(\frac{π}{9}) = \sqrt[3]
{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{16} + \sqrt{\frac{3}{256} - \frac{1}{64}}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{16} - \sqrt{\frac{3}{256} - \frac{1}{64}}}$
Which ultimately simplifies into
$\frac{\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{3} + i} + \sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{3} - i}}{2\sqrt[3]{2}}$
And that's where the problem lies.

Of course, I'll need to verify that **this** is between 0 and 1, and right now, I'm not even sure it's a real number. So I'll need to get rid of the $i$s if I can; I cannot do that while they're under cube root, so I'll have to solve the roots first.

In order to solve the roots, I'll have to convert my complex numbers into the polar form first, then get the cube root of the distance and the third of the angle, and that's where my predicament becomes more apparent.

$-\sqrt{3} + i$ and $-\sqrt{3} - i$ are $2\angle\frac{5π}{6}$ and $2\angle\frac{7π}{6}$ respectively. My problem is that those angles are multiples of $\frac{π}{6}$, which means that when I take the cube root, they'll be multiples of $\frac{π}{18}$, which I don't know the sine and cosine of, and for which I need to derive them for $\frac{π}{9}$ in the first place. Same thing happens with the cosine (but the angles there are multiple of $\frac{π}{3}$ instead).

Now, there's an obvious solution to this, figuring out a way to take the cube root of a complex number algebraically (without converting into the polar form), but I've looked it up and found nothing. There might also be a way different way entirely of deriving this, but there are none I know of. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: We can never find the values of $\sin \frac π9$ or $\cos \frac π9$ with real-valued algebraic radicals.  Because this is case of [Casus irreducibilis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis), which is known in mathematics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to express $\sin \frac{\pi}{9}$ in terms of radicals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593412/is-it-possible-to-express-sin-frac-pi9-in-terms-of-radicals) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csin(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B9%7D)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Ccos(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B9%7D)%24&p=1). Also, there are additional related questions, e.g., [Closed-form of $\tan(\frac{\pi }{9})$.](/q/996600), [Algebraic values of the sine function](/q/1122095), etc.

Comment: I have one more question. If it's a casus irreducibilis, how can we tell it's a real number? That's why I was determined to get rid of $i$ in the first place, I wanna prove it's real.

Comment: For the casus irreducubilis see my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2838797.

Comment: @lonestudent It is not correct that in the casus irreducibilis one can **never** find solutions with real-valued algebraic radicals. If we are lucky, the cubic radicals can be denested. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4148105. Also see Remarks 1, 2 in my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2838797.

Comment: @PaulFrost Can you provide a precise example, that seems interesting ?

Comment: @lonestudent Read the remarks in the linked question.

Comment: @lonestudent $x^3 -15x - 4 = 0$ from Remark 2.

Comment: @Paul But, this cubic is not an irreducible polynomial. I will analyze the topic again, thank you for your remarks .

Comment: @lonestudent All cubic polynomials are reducible. Perhaps you mean that it has rational coefficients and is reducible in the ring of rational polynomials? Anyway, my comment only concerned your "never" statement. The cubic radicals occurring in the Cardano formula can be denested in some special cases.